# Bootstraps 3 background color to change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and i want to change the background color and hover state for the links for **.navbar-inverse**. I tried every single thing and classes, without any luck. Its still showing the same dark gradient.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="hotel"><a href="index.html">Hotel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rooms_suites.html">Rooms & Suites</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reservation.html">Reservation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- End Of Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser's developer tools can easily help you to find the correct selectors to use. `Right Click > Inspect Element`

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
        color: red;
        background: green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/EqupyHFh04)